# RPA : How to do back-end automation using RPA tools?

Tags: python-3.x, rpa, automationanywhere

I would like to know how back-end automation is possible through RPA.

I'd be interested in solving this scenario relative to an **Incident Management Application**, in which authentication is required. The app provide:

1. An option useful to download/export the report to a `csv` file
2. Sort the `csv` as per the requirement
3. Send an email with the updated csv to the team

Please let me know how this possible through RPA and what are those tools 
available in RPA to automate this kind of scenario?

Comment: You don't need UI integration in the backend. RPA is only needed (if at all) when an application has no other way of integration except the UI. If a server has SOAP or HTTP APIs, you can call them directly. There are a *lot* of BPM and orchestration products, both at the high end like Microsoft Biztalk and Oracle BPM and the low, OSS end like Apache Airlfow

Comment: In any case, what you describe isn't even automation. Every database has a way to schedule a job to extract query results in a CSV and email them. Most web sites have automated emails too, using either cron jobs or libraries

Comment: There are in fact MANY back end tools in so-called "RPA" suites, including file management, API transactions and database transactions, but the whole "category" is confusing because the vendors are expanding the toolsets all the time, as well as the category names. There was BPA, Workflow, Doc Processing and RPA, all merging now. Everybody is confused and this question might well be moved out of stack overflow and into the forums for software engineering or software package selection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. It is especially useful when your backed are 3rd party applications where you do not have lot of control. Many RPA products like Softomotive WinAutomation, Automation Anywhere, UiPath etc. provide file utilities, excel utilities, db utilities, ability to call apis, OCR capabilities etc., which you can use for backed automation.

Comment: There's no reason to use UI integration techniques when you already have back-end integration features. In fact, by definition, it's *impossible* to use RPA in the back-end where there's no UI. If you don't use the UI, you aren't doing RPA, you're doing good old automation, the way Oracle BPM, Microsoft's Biztalk or SSIS, Apache Airflow and dozens of mature integration and business process automation services do, for decades

Comment: Besides, the question asks for periodic emailing of data, something easily done with a cron job or a scheduled job in any database, or with libraries on a web site. Web sites don't use RPA to send confirmation emails

Answer (score 2):

RPA tools are designed to automate mainly **front-end** activities by mimicing human actions. It can be done easily using any RPA tool.

However, if you are interested in **back-end** automation the first question would be, if specific application has an option to interact in the way you want through the back-end/API?
If yes, in theory you could develop RPA robot to run pre-developed back-end script. However, if all you need would be to run this script, creating robot for this case may be redundant.